# undefined action call from userstore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, expo, mobx

3.5 and Expo version 43

we are moving an existng code file over to use in expo our user store model...
having a hard time reaching the .actions items and no idea how to research this.

example code of where we are trying to use the action in

```
 const { userStore } = useStores()


 const onPressLogIn = async () => {
debugger
console.log("pressed login")
console.log(userStore)  //also undefined
if (validateText()) {
  setLoading(true)
  props.navigation.setParams({ noback: true })
  userStore.logInUser(email, password)
  // .then(async () => {
    //   return logInStatus
    // })
    // .catch(() => {
    //   setLoading(false)
    //   props.navigation.setParams({ noback: false })
    //   setError(userStore.friendlyLoginStatus)
    // })
}
}
```

**Using mobx-state-tree lib for state handling and firebase Auth**

```
async logInUser(email: string, password: string) {
      const auth = getAuth()
      signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in 
        const user = userCredential.user;
        // ...
      })
      // await self.loginSuccess(data.user, "email")
      // return Promise.resolve()

  },
```

**WHERE WE IMPORT USER STORE FROM ***
import { createContext, useContext } from "react"
import { RootStore } from "./root-store"

```
const RootStoreContext = createContext<RootStore>({} as RootStore)


export const RootStoreProvider = RootStoreContext.Provider

export const useStores = () => useContext(RootStoreContext)
```

*** THE root-store file

```
import { Instance, SnapshotOut, types } from "mobx-state-tree"

import { creatMediaPlayerModel } from "../../models/media-player"
import { createUserModel } from "../../models/user"
import { createContentModel } from "../../models/content"

// /**
//  * A RootStore model.
//  */
export const RootStoreModel = types.model("RootStore").props({
mediaPlayerStore: creatMediaPlayerModel(),
userStore: createUserModel(),
contentStore: createContentModel(),
})

// /**
//  * The RootStore instance.
//  */
export type RootStore = Instance<typeof RootStoreModel>

// /**
//  * The data of a RootStore.
//  */
export type RootStoreSnapshot = SnapshotOut<typeof RootStoreModel>
```

Any ideas? Tips? is the whole login method wrinted wrong? debugger shows up as loginuser is undefined

[image]

Comment: Where does `useStores` come from? What state management library are you using? What does `console.log(userStore)` show? Where/how is `logInUser()` defined?

Comment: edited the question with above mentions

Comment: so loginuser is within the .actions of the userstore model file

Comment: It seems that `const { userStore } = useStores()` does not return what you expect it to. So where does that get wired up? And what does `console.log(useStores())` return? Actually it doesn't look like `useStores` is part of the MobX API, so it's a custom hook? So what's in that custom hook? I don't know MobX at all, I'm just helping you debug...

Comment: gonna add to the question too long for edit

Comment: You're using a context in `useContext(RootStoreContext)`. Do you create that `<RootStoreContext value={{ ... }} />` context provider and provide it values? Is your component a child of that context?

Comment: good question that was from the old code files too let me make sure i added everything over

Comment: see commented out rootstore items in our app.tsx old file gonna start there!

Comment: @AlexWayne thank you for helping it was the app.tsx file :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my comment that helped as an answer:

You're using a context in

```
useContext(RootStoreContext)
```

And the behaviour you describe is what happens when the context provider is not ever setup.

So you need to make sure that the provider is setup and is given values:

```
<RootStoreContext.Provider value={{ ... }}>
  <MyComponent />
</RootStoreContext.Provider>
```

And that the components that need access to that context are children of that provider.

Comment: circling back to this... now we get invalid react hooks when using our main app 

   <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
      {renderContent()}
    </RootStoreProvider>

Comment: I believe you need to use JSX syntax here like `<RootComponent />`. Functions that return JSX don't know where there are in the DOM when they render, and that's very import for context. So try converting `renderContent()` into a functional component instead.

Comment: oh - did not think of that

Comment: <RootStoreProvider value={rootStore}>
            <SafeAreaProvider>
            <Navigation colorScheme={colorScheme} />
            <StatusBar />
            </SafeAreaProvider>
      </RootStoreProvider>


swapped for this and still get hook error

Comment: This sounds like a different issue. Please post a new separate question with the exactly what error you are seeing and what your code looks like now and I will keep an eye out for it and try to give you answer.

Comment: ok - thanks. will try to figure out where in this massive code pile it is breaking first